# Is it possible to only allow a chrome extension to make an http request an no one else?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httprequest

I want to make a chrome extension that communicates with my server via http requests, but i don't want anyone else to be able to spoof and pretend to be the extension and make the same requests on their own.

But since all of the extension code is accessible to the users, is there any way to do this?

Comment: if you're using HTTP protocol, Well... I don't think it's possible.

Comment: http or https is irrelevant

Comment: Generally it is impossible for any client-side app based on any technology. The most closest way to do it is using `https` and `certificate pinning`. For instance right now spoofing and sniffing traffic between AppStore app on iOS and server side infrastructure is very difficult but still possible.

Comment: @Valentin Certificate pinning has absolutely _nothing_ to do with this. It would prevent a legitimate client connecting to a spoofed server, but does not prevent a spoofed client to connect.

Comment: @Xan, you are right. Also certificate pinning can make protocol reverse engineering even harder if there is no access to source code of original client app.

Comment: Sadly, we are talking about a Chrome Extension, that is inevitably supplied with a super-convenient debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. Any sort of client secret is visible upon inspection.

The most you can do is to make some authentication scheme (like OAuth) that assigns individual, temporary, revocable tokens to extension instances. This way, if you catch a stolen token you can revoke it, at least mitigating the unauthorized traffic.

You could even request users to register for your server, to make identification of misbehaving clients easier and re-authentication harder. But that might turn off some users.